# _find query not working in ibm cloudant

Tags: jquery, cors, couchdb, cloudant

I'm using cloudant, CORS is enabled, all queries are working except `_find`.

My find query is working very well against a local CouchDB with this code:

```
var urlPrefix = "http://localhost:5984/etablissements";

var query = {
  "selector": {
   "cp": 24000
  }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  urlPrefix + '/_find',
    contentType: "application/json", 
    data:JSON.stringify(query),
    success: function(data) {
           console.log(data.docs);
            // do whatever with data.docs there

     }

 });
```

Now, I want to make a CORS jQuery AJAX call online, and do the same query as my first one, against my IBM Cloudant database, but it doesn't work, while it is the same query, and the same replicated database.

CORS is enabled on Cloudant.

```
urlPrefix = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST.cloudant.com/etablissements";

    var query = {
      "selector": {
       "cp": 24000
      }
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  urlPrefix + '/_find',
        contentType: "application/json", 
        data:JSON.stringify(query),
        dataType: 'json',

        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
             'withCredentials': true // tell the client to send the cookies if any for the requested domain
          },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.docs);

            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }

     });
```

I haven't received any error message coming from Cloudant. I just get this error message from jQuery:

```
  {…}
​
abort: function abort()
​
always: function always()
​
catch: function catch()
​
done: function add()
​
fail: function add()
​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
​
pipe: function pipe()
​
progress: function add()
​
promise: function promise()
​
readyState: 0
​
responseJSON: undefined
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 0
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "error"
​
then: function then()
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Others query from this document (like 'all' for example) are currently working:

http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/

**EDIT :** Glynn, Still gettin the same error with the lastest firefox version and your copy pasted code, no ajax call is done, instead, it goes through the jquery error process :

[image]

**EDIT 2  :** I've changed a few Glynn's code and it has worked in chrome but i've had to provide credentials inside a popup coming from Chrome. Please notice that i've removed the login password from the urlPrefix variable, and that the username and password provided inside jquery are not working. So it is not the good solution yet. Firefox is still failing with the error showed above :

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
     var urlPrefix = "https://1c54473b-be6e-42d6-b914-d0ecae937981-bluemix.cloudant.com/etablissements";
      var query = {
        "selector": {
         "cp": 24000
        }
      };
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  urlPrefix + '/_find',
          contentType: "application/json", 
          data:JSON.stringify(query),
          dataType: 'json',
          crossDomain: true,
          username: "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-42d6-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-bluemix",
          password:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          xhrFields: {
               'withCredentials': true // tell the client to send the cookies if any for the requested domain
            },
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error:function(data){
              console.log(data);
          }
       });
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

**EDIT 3 : SOLVED !**

I have succeeded to make it work with the help of this page :
 https://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication

So this is my final code, tested in firefox, chrome and opera, and finally working ! So i'm now able to do _find queries with CORS enabled on cloudant and i LOVE IT !

Please notice that the key to the solution was the **jquery beforeSend() functio**n, you need to provide the **credentials** there :

```
   <html><meta charset="utf-8" />
    <head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script>
     var urlPrefix = "https://1c54473b-be6e-42d6-b914-d0ecae937981-bluemix.cloudant.com/etablissements";
     var USERNAME = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-42d6-b914-d0ecae937981-bluemix";
     var PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb9e74af7368b21a37b531aae819929d3405c7d22";

      var query = {
        "selector": {
         "cp": 24000
        }
      };
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json", 
          data:JSON.stringify(query),
          dataType: 'json',
          crossDomain: true,
           xhrFields: {
               'withCredentials': true // tell the client to send the cookies if any for the requested domain
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '  + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));
          },
            url:  urlPrefix + '/_find',

          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error:function(data){
              console.log(data);
          }
       });


       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Doing CORS apps is so usefulll for building quick labos apps ! I love this no server technology, please DONT STOP this !!

Comment: I don't know if you're aware but PouchDB would highly simplify access to cloudant. Also, what is the http response from your request? You can see that in the dev console

Comment: Hello Alexis, yes, i love the pouchdb technology, but i'm willing to make couchdb works 100% before using pouchdb . thank you ! in this case, there was no http response at all, only the jquery error displayed

Comment: i dont want to use pouchdb for now, i dont want to get a local replication.

Comment: You can use PouchDB as a client for your remote database. There's no need for local database

Comment: Really ? Wow thats a nice information ure giving me !

Answer (score 0):

When debugging such thins, I would first check whether your query works from the Cloudant Dashboard or from the command-line:

```
curl -X POST \ 
  -d'{"selector": { "cp": 24000}}' \ 
  -H'Content-type: application/json' \
 "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST.cloudant.com/etablissements/_find"
```

The answer is "yes, it works!". You get an object back that contains `{"docs": [ ... ]}` with an array of documents.

So I set about testing your jQuery code, and it works if you remove the rogue `}` in the `success` function:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  var urlPrefix = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST.cloudant.com/etablissements";
  var query = {
    "selector": {
     "cp": 24000
    }
  };
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:  urlPrefix + '/_find',
      contentType: "application/json", 
      data:JSON.stringify(query),
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      xhrFields: {
           'withCredentials': true // tell the client to send the cookies if any for the requested domain
        },
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data.docs);
      },
      error:function(data){
          console.log(data);
      }
   });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

N.B Please don't publish your Cloudant credentials in the public domain.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying out your jquery code and have posted my error in my main comment, thank you. i'm using firefox lastest version. The bracket was a copy paste mistake but not present in the original code. I'v got jquery throwing an error, and no ajax query is fired. I'm adding a screen copy, with the error throwing, using your code. I'm conecting through 3g moblie phone but it is not a problem for others queries

Comment: This is really a big problem for me because it means i can't query the cloudant database with _find , while it is working very well on my localhost couchdb.

Comment: I'd like to leave my credentials, it is a testing environnement, i 'dlike somebody to test out and tell me why it is not working thank you

Comment: I've tested the above code and it works just fine against your Cloudant service.

Comment: Thanks, did you try with firefox  or chrome ?

Comment: error 401  in chrome or opera, fails silently in firefox . If i specify withCredentials, i need to authenticate inside a popup which is not convenient.

Comment: Finally solved ! Thanks a lot for your help, i was missing the jquery beforeSend() function